# Seamless SSO between two applications in Angular 8

Tags: auth0

Within Auth0, I have a single tenant with two applications:

1. Admin = Regular Web Application
2. UI = Single Page Application

Within the same browser, I have two tabs open.  The first, I login to Admin.  I then go to the 2nd tab, which is the UI, and refresh the page, which results in returning to my callback page with the query parameters `error=login_required&error_description=Login%20required&state=[longstring]` and within the Auth0 logs I am getting a `Failed Silent Auth` error.

I have used this code: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login.  Only changing the redirect_uri so that it goes `${window.location.origin}/callback` and removing `this.handleAuthCallback();` from the constructor.

My callback component is like this:

```
export class CallbackComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private auth: Auth0Service) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.handleAuthCallback()
  }

}
```

I'm not sure what to try next.  This is what I'd expect to happen:

1. If user has an active session in this tenant they are automatically logged in
2. If they do not, they are shown the Universal Login screen instead of just getting the login failed

Comment: Did you find any resolutions to this?

Comment: @PankajPrakash I did not.  The business ended up deciding to not use Auth0